# How can I get a pointer to a resource via a base type handle without dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, resource-management

I'm building my own pet engine and after struggling with how to handle resource ownership for a while, I came across [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58864/how-can-a-resource-manager-have-dynamic-loading-unloading-without-creating-dangl/58865) and specifically Josh and Sean's responses (as well as [Sean's blog on shared_ptr](http://seanmiddleditch.com/journal/2014/01/dangers-of-stdshared_ptr/)), which really made a whole lot of sense to me. So I went ahead and implemented my own similar system, and so far it's working great except for one minor snag - what do I do when I need to access a resource of a derived type when the handle only refers to the base type?

Say for instance I have a Material class that keeps a list of handles to textures it needs for rendering:

```
class Material
{
public:
    void SetTexture(int textureSlot, const Handle<Texture>& texture);
private:
    SomeContainer<Handle<Texture>> m_textures;
};
```

Then I grab a handle to a texture from my texture library, set it to the material, and everything works great:

```
Handle<Texture> fnorbTexture = TextureLibary::GetResource("fnorb.tga");
fnorbMaterial->SetTexture(0, fnorbTexture); // fnorbtastic!
```

But what happens now when I have a RenderTarget class that derives from Texture?

```
class GraphicsSystem
{
public:
    void SetRenderTarget(int slot, Handle<RenderTarget> renderTarg);
    // Other stuff
};

Handle<Texture> renderTarg = 
    TextureLibrary::PleaseGiveMeARenderTarget(width, height, flags);

// ERROR: Can't cast Handle<Texture> to Handle<RenderTarget>!
graphicsSystem->SetRenderTarget(0, renderTarg); 
// ... Render stuff to render target ...

// Set the current render target back to the standard frame buffer
graphicsSystem->SetRenderTarget(0, kNullHandle);
// Now use the render target as a texture
superAwesomeBlorgomaticPostEffectMaterial->SetTexture(0, renderTarg); // OK!
```

Or maybe:

```
Handle<RenderTarget> renderTarg = 
    RenderTargetLibrary::PleaseGiveMeARenderTarget(width, height, flags);

graphicsSystem->SetRenderTarget(0, renderTarg); // OK!
// ... Render stuff to render target ...

// Set the current render target back to the standard frame buffer
graphicsSystem->SetRenderTarget(0, kNullHandle);
// Now use the render target as a texture
// ERROR: Can't cast Handle<RenderTarget> to Handle<Texture>!
superAwesomeBlorgomaticPostEffectMaterial->SetTexture(0, renderTarg);
```

Possible solutions, and my thoughts on each:

Borrow a render target resource as a `Handle<RenderTarget>`, and in `Material::SetTexture()`, pass it using `reinterpret_cast<const Handle<Texture>&>`.

- Compiles and probably works, but looks ugly and I feel dirty afterwards.

Or: Borrow a render target resource as a `Handle<Texture>`, and rewrite `SetRenderTarget` to take a `const Handle<Texture>&` instead. Then:

- When I dereference the handle, use `dynamic_cast` to cast the pointer to a `RenderTarget*` as necessary.

  - RTTI is "Bad" TM, which is to say that it very often gets disabled (along with C++ exceptions, etc.) in game applications due to unnecessary overhead, particularly on consoles. Plus resorting to `dynamic_cast` feels like I'm "doing it wrong," architecturally speaking.
- I know it's a `RenderTarget`; it was when I created it, and if it weren't, I wouldn't be passing it to `SetRenderTarget` in the first place! `reinterpret_cast`!

  - Do I REALLY know? If I'm wrong, then I'm casting something else to something it's not, and I can't even check if it's `nullptr` if I'm wrong. Also, again, I'd like to avoid casts if possible. But I don't entirely disagree with the logic here...
- Implement a lightweight homegrown alternative to RTTI, and use that instead.

  - I've seen this done in one or two engines, but it sounds like some fairly heavy-duty wheel-reinventing...
- Don't derive `RenderTarget` from `Texture`; instead, add a flag that says whether a `Texture` is a `RenderTarget` or not. If it's not, then `SetRenderTarget` will simply fail.

  - Potentially lots of excess baggage added to the `Texture` class. (What's another pointer to an `ID3D11RenderTargetView` among friends?) Doesn't sound like it scales very well.
- Derive `RenderTarget` from `Texture`, but add a virtual method to `Texture` called `GetRenderTarget()` that normally returns `nullptr` but is overridden in `RenderTarget` to return `this`. Similar to the flag method above, but without the excess baggage.

  - Feels like a poor man's `dynamic_cast`. Again, doesn't scale well (add a new method for each derived class that needs it?). But if my `RenderTarget` scenario is maybe the only case I actually need something like this, I'm beginning to feel like maybe this solution isn't so bad...

Or maybe: Add another `SetTexture()` method to `Material` that takes a `const Handle<RenderTarget>&` instead?

- Again, scaleability. And this almost certainly complicates the implementation...

Or finally: Somehow make a handle to a derived type automagically compatible with a handle to its base type (without say, deriving `Handle<RenderTarget>` from `Handle<Texture>`)? I feel like theoretically this might be possible, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it at the moment. Template metaprogramming magic?

Wow, this got a lot longer than I thought it would. Is there a better solution that I'm just missing? Or is one of the above a good enough answer? Feel free to tear apart my arguments if they're flawed. I feel like I'm vastly overthinking this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what happens now when I have a RenderTarget class that **derives** from Texture?

I highlighted the problem with your design.

A `RenderTarget` is not a `Texture`.  It *has* a `Texture`.  The `RenderTarget` is just a view (either literally as in `ID3D11RenderTargetView` in Direct3D or as an FBO in OpenGL) into a `Texture`.  There's some potential issues with flags when creating a texture in some APIs and whether it can later be wrapped as a render target, but that's a data issue, not a type system issue.

You can use code like:

```
Handle<RenderTarget> rt = ...;
Handle<Texture> tex = rt->GetBackingTexture();
```

The `RenderTarget` class would have something like this at a minimum:

```
class RenderTarget : public Resource {
  Handle<Texture> m_BAckingTexture;
  CComPtr<ID3D11RenderTargetView> m_RenderTargetView;

public:
  const Handle<Texture>& GetBackingTexture() const { return m_BackingTexture; }
};
```

Now you can create `RenderTarget` resources from any compatible `Texture` resource and you can retrieve the original `Texture` from any `RenderTarget`.  There is no need to "convert" one to the other because they are entirely separate objects.

As (almost) always, prefer aggregation over inheritance.  *has-a*, not *is-a*.

Comment: Wow! Of course! Thanks, Sean; your answer makes so much sense I feel almost silly for not realizing it in the first place (and silly for posting such a huge question). Once again, you are the man, Sean! Sorry I don't have the reputation to upvote your answer. I think I may have been temporarily blinded by my experience with Unity, where RenderTexture derives from Texture...